# Saving elements of RDD in Spark application

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I am running spark application on a cluster. I want perform some operation on each of the elements in RDD and save each element into a textfile.

I am calling `foreach` on myRDD

```py
  myRDD.foreach(process)

   def process(elements):
        // some operation that extracts the strings
        // and converts to myList
        myList = ... 

        with open("somefile.txt", "a+") as myfile:
            print "----SAVED----"
            myfile.writelines(myList)
```

However, i am not able to find the somefile.txt even though I do find that the print statement gets printed without any errors/warning.  Where is somefile.txt saved? If my methods is incorrect, how do i save individual elements of RDD?

Comment: I would like to save myList using foreach ? is it possible.. if not then how do i perform operation on each element on RDD and save the generated output which is in form of list..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
myRDD.map(convertToList).saveAsTextFile(<hdfs output path>)
```

With this approach you will be able to scale your application, if you have to transfer all your data into the driver, then you will warranty that the output data is enough small to fit in driver memory or you will start having troubles.

If you require that all the data end in only one file then (This approach have a similar problem than transfer all the output to the driver, not scalable):

```
myRDD.map(generateList).coalesce(1).saveAsTextFile(<hdfs output path>)
```

If you require to convert your list in a String before it being stored in the file then:

```
myRDD.map(generateList).map(listToString).saveAsTextFile(<hdfs output path>)
```

Obviously you can convert your list into a String inside the first map and save an extra step.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so the reason this is problematic is an RDD is not necessarily on a single node. Your RDD when you call `foreach` is distributed across your nodes. You need to either collect your RDD to the driver node using `collect` or [use the built in file writer, but this won't modify it.](https://databricks.gitbooks.io/databricks-spark-reference-applications/content/logs_analyzer/chapter3/save_the_rdd_to_files.html)

`collect` might be better but it also bottlenecks because now all the data is being collected into a single node (the driver node.)

Edit: I'm going to answer your additional questions with some code...

```py
def process(element):
  #process element to a list
  return myList

def writeList(myList):
  with open('somefile.txt', 'a+') as f:
    f.writelines(myList)

#in main
myListRDD = myRDD.map(process)
myListRDD.collect().foreach(writeList)
```

That should do what you want while being efficient. Because we process to a new RDD for the Lists, we are able to do all processing parallel, so the only linear operation is the file writing, which needs to occur at a single node for data coherency.

Comment: yep, how do i collect the myList back in driver node?

Comment: @vkb You simply do `val myRDDArr = myRDD.collect()` this will pull all the RDD data into an Array stored in `myRDDArr` on the driver node.

Comment: each element is passed to a function 'process' on which i perform certain operations returning a list. my end goal is to save the list in text file. So do you mean myRDD.foreach(process).collect() ?

Comment: @vkb Does process work on each element of the RDD? If so we can do `val myListRDD = myRDD.map(process)` and make sure process returns the list you need saved. Then `myListRDD.collect().foreach(writeData)` this would allow the processing to happen in parallel. So simply remove your file writing from the `process` function and put that in a new function `writeData`

Comment: Thats sweet.. here the problem is doing foreach and saving through a function would save the elements in a location which is not clear.. thats my original problem as well